# Storing Google App Engine User Nicknames with PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, authorization

Using Google App Engine with PHP, I would like to use User Services to authorize the user. I want to store the user's preference and other custom information to a database and relate this data to the user. Is it safe to store the nickname from getNickname() as a unique id and relate the information to the user? Is the nickname unique per app?

My goal is that when a user visits the website, the app checks the user's nickname to nicknames stored on the database and will be able to dynamically change the website to the user's preference. Is there something wrong with this approach?

I'll appreciate any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's very rare that the nickname will ever change is still possible, so your best option use user's ID by calling the [`getUserId()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/refdocs/classes/google.appengine.api.users.User#method_getUserId) instead.

Comment: The documentation says "If the email address was set explicity, this will return null" for getUserId(). However, the nickname doesn't have this, so that is why I thought it would be a better choice.

Comment: Not sure how you can login without being associated with a Google account.. but here you can read more on each value: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass the choice is yours :)

Comment: Thank you! The link you provided is helpful.